# NSTextField does not update calculated property using Core Data bindings

Tags: cocoa-bindings, key-value-observing, nstextfield, nsarraycontroller, nsset

New to SO; my first question:

Re: Core Data, document based app using bindings:

I have an **NSTableView** bound to an **NSArrayController**, bound to an entity, **LineItem**, with several columns bound to the following **LineItem** attributes/properties: *amount*, *price*, and *total*. I'm using +**keyPathsForValuesAffectingTotal** to observe changes in *amount* and *price*. The property, *total*, updates instantly with any changes. 
I have another entity, **Item**. It has a one to many relationship (*items*) with **LineItem** since every **Item**  can have many **LineItems**. **Item** also has an **NSTableView** bound to an **NSArrayController**, which is bound to its respective entity, **Item**. This table has several columns as well, but one is, *lineItemTotal* (items.@sum.total).

```
- (NSNumber *)lineItemTotal {
     float totalOfAllLineItemTotals = [[self valueForKeyPath:@"items.@sum.total"]floatValue];
     [self willAccessValueForKey:@"lineItemTotal"];
     return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:totalOfAllLineItemTotals];
     [self didAccessValueForKey:@"lineItemTotal"];
     return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:totalOfAllLineItemTotals];
}
```

The *lineItemTotal* value updates instantly with the use of an **NSNotification** *NSManagedObjectContextObjectsDidChangeNotification*, which calls my selector, updateLineItemTotal: which sends a message: [self.view setNeedsDisplay:YES]; 
Everything works fine... However, this view should look like a receipt. As such, I have an NSTextField underneath the **LineItem** Table to show the total, as the user would expect. I have tried binding it to the same **NSArrayController** that **Item** is, but this does not work. In the bindings Inspector, I cannot choose **arrangedObjects** for the **Controller Key**, since it isn't a table. (this is how the Item Table is set up and working fine) My only choice is 'selection' for the **Controller Key**. In any case, it always shows the correct value, but only after I create a new Item instance (via **NSButton** bound to add:) and return to the old Item instance. It does not update instantly like everything else: a user would find this unprofessional. I've tried the suggestions of Hillegass, searched Stack Overflow, and Apple's recommended work arounds regarding updating values when dealing with an **NSSet**. Apple recommends setting up a notification. I did that and this time it didn't work. I've tried all the obvious workarounds with no success. I believe it comes down to **KVC** & **KVO**; unfortunately, Apple has little support for these powerful tools when working with **NSSets**, at least not on the surface. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The first problem I see here is that you appear to be returning from this method before all the statements have executed:

```
- (NSNumber *)lineItemTotal {
     float totalOfAllLineItemTotals = [[self valueForKeyPath:@"items.@sum.total"]floatValue];
     [self willAccessValueForKey:@"lineItemTotal"];
     return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:totalOfAllLineItemTotals];
     // Anything below here will never be executed.
     [self didAccessValueForKey:@"lineItemTotal"];
     return [NSNumber numberWithFloat:totalOfAllLineItemTotals];
}
```

Even so, I took a few minutes and coded this up, and it appears from my experience that the collection operators (i.e. @sum) don't work with CoreData lazy fetched sets. Any attempts I made netted me errors like:

```
[<_NSFaultingMutableSet 0x101922270> addObserver:forKeyPath:options:context:] is not supported. Key path: @sum.total
```

Luckily, it appears that you can use the NSArrayController to enable this collection operator.  I put the version I coded [up on github](https://github.com/ipmcc/SOExamples/tree/master/bindings/SOTotal). I believe I have covered all the bases you were trying to achieve there. I've got the master/detail table views and the extra text field, all live updating, etc.